# Why can't python ast detect an if statement within a function?

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I am a newbie to ASTs as I come from a Statistics background. As per my observation, Python is unable to detect an if statement for the following code -

```
import ast
from pprint import pprint

tree = ast.parse("""
def add(a, b):
  return a + b

def subr(a,b):
    if 2>3:
        print("true")
    else:
        print("false")
    return 0
""")




for node in ast.iter_child_nodes(tree):
    print(isinstance(node, ast.If))
```

However, if there is no function, it can detect the if statement -

```
import ast
from pprint import pprint

tree = ast.parse("""
if 2>3:
    print("true")
else:
    print("false")
""")




for node in ast.iter_child_nodes(tree):
    print(isinstance(node, ast.If))
```

Could someone please tell me what is the problem with my former code block?

Comment: If you step through the code in a debugger, you can see that you are not iterating through all the child nodes' own child nodes. You are only looking one level deep. So, the `if` statement will only be found if it is one level deep, unless you *recursively* iterate through the nodes, I think.

Comment: `iter_child_nodes()` only iterates immediate child nodes of the argument - you probably want `ast.walk()` to recurse through the whole tree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mathias R. Jessen is correct. `iter_child_nodes()` can only iterate through immediate child nodes. To iterate through the entire code, one should use `ast.walk()`